# How to play video from website in android?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget, android-video-player

How can I play videos from URL in android?. without new Intent?. is available?
Thanks

Comment: [Please do some searching before you ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+play+video+from+url)

Comment: is available? => **Yes there are many thread exist here on SO for the same topic and The best Google is there**

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String url="your video url";
VideoView videoView = new VideoView(this);
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url));
setContentView(videoView);
videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
```

hope help

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...It should work fine.

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
String link = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lEbxLDuecHU&playnext=1&list=PL040F3034C69B1674";
Uri videoLink = Uri.parse(link);
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
videoView.setVideoURI(videoLink);
videoView.start();
```